# android GPS enable when button click

Tags: android, gps, android-alertdialog

this is my Code. ( it make alertdialog to move Settings)
but I just want to enable GPS when I "ENABLE GPS" button click.
and Does android alway enable button click when I run app not just run once?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Your GPS is disabled! Would you like to enable it?")
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("Enable GPS",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        moveConfigGPS();
    }
}).setNegativeButton("Do nothing",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

```
  /**
 * Check if GPS enabled or not
 * and request dialog to enable GPS.
 */
private void checkWhetherLocationSettingsAreSatisfied() {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(1000)
            .setNumUpdates(2);

    final LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    builder.setNeedBle(true);
    SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
    Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
    task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess() called with: locationSettingsResponse = [" + locationSettingsResponse + "]");
            hasLocationPermission();

        }
    });
    task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess --> onFailure() called with: e = [" + e + "]");
            if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                // by showing the user a dialog.
                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                    ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    resolvable.startResolutionForResult(BaseActivity.this,
                            Constants.REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {

        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            hasLocationPermission();

        } else {
            //User clicks No
        }
    }

}
```

I think you want to turn on GPS location with one click like Google do.

[image]

To prompt the user for permission to modify the location settings, call startResolutionForResult(Activity, int). This method brings up a dialog asking for the user's permission to modify location settings.

Comment: hey, is there a way to detect when user clicks No from the above dialog???

Comment: Yes. You will get resultCode in onActivityResult

Comment: I tried but couldn't get so anyways thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thanks , Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can't just enable GPS, you can only open gps settings with this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    User these method to on GPS :

    intent1 = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
     startActivity(intent1);

and add these method to check GPS is on or Off ??
public void CheckGpsStatus(){

 locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

 GpsStatus = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

 if(GpsStatus == true)
 {
 textview.setText("Location Services Is Enabled"); 
 }else {
 textview.setText("Location Services Is Disabled"); 
 }

 }
```